# Can't access SSRS Report Server using Host Name

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver

I have a local installation of SSRS Report Server (2017). If I try and access the reports portal using http://*HostName*/Reports I get a "This page can't be displayed" error. If however I use http://localhost/Reports the portal loads. I have a separate issue and by solving the issue described I'm hoping that this other issue will resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Command Prompt - Start Menu -> cmd and type:

```
hostname
```

to check if you have the hostname correct. If you do, open the

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

file in notepad and check if there are any lines relating to your hostname or local ip.

If not, then go back to command prompt and do

```
nslookup
```

then type your hostname

```
[HostnameFromAboveStep]
```

and see which IP Address is reported, then type

```
ipconfig
```

and see which IP you actually have

Comment: There's no entry in the hosts file for the hostname (in fact the other entries were commenting out with an additional comment saying localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself). When I enter the hostname in nslookup I get a Can't find hostname: Server failed error.

Comment: @user10202147 Okay so it looks like your computer is missing its DNS entry. What network are you on? Are you on a Domain? Ask your network admin to set up DNS properly - or add an entry in the hosts file like 127.0.0.1       [YourHostName] (although note that will only fix it from your local PC not from other network computers)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll speak to my network admin and see what they advise